# Mascarar uma div com css

Tags: css, html5

Em um site que estou desenvolvendo o topo (onde estão os menus) tem o fundo transparente e é fixo. Ou seja, o site roda por trás desse topo e o topo fica sempre fixo.

Mas como ele é transparante... o site acaba ficando atras do topo quando dou o scroll.

Existe alguma forma de deixar o site mascarado? Ou seja... onde esta o menu ele não aparece, veja a imagem para explica melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem algum exemplo funcional? URL para acessar ou JSFiddle para entender melhor?

Comment: Você quer que o resto do site não apareça por baixo do menu quando fizer rolagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não vai colocar nada de `background` no menu, então algumas soluções que vejo são:

`body{
     overflow-y: hidden;
}`

`#site{ /*esse site aqui é o id da sua div abaixo do topo*/
    overflow-y: visible;
}`

Ou seja, vai rolar apenas a div de baixo.

Outra opção seria utilizar `jquery`, que alteraria a cor das palavras do seu menus fixo ao rolar a página:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 50){ //quando rolar mais de 50px muda a cor
            $('elemento_menu').css('color','blue'); //escolhe a cor que melhor contrastar
        }
    });
});`

Comment: Boa ideia!

Mas e a barra de rolagem? Pois o site tem um max-width de 1000px... e em monitores grandes a barra de rolagem vai aparecer dentro do site... e não no canto